# How do I avoid #value in my excel sum equation?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

When summing for the cells with nothing in them, I get `#value` using this formula

```
=CB85+CC85
```

Yet I don't get it when I use this equation:

```
=SUM(CI157:CJ157)
```

But on using `=SUM(CI157:CJ157)` I get a summation with an error telling me that formula omits adjacent cells when there are figures that are not zero in the cells?

How can I avoid the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the cells contains a value that cannot be summed, probably a text value.

The + operator cannot handle text values and will throw an error. The Sum() function can tolerate text values. It will just ignore them and sum just the numbers.

The warning that adjacent cells have been omitted in the formula is just that: A warning. It's not an error and does not do any harm. If it annoys you, you can use the Excel options (File > Options > Formulas) to turn selected error check warnings off.